# setFirstResult and setMaxResult with JDBC template

Tags: hibernate, join, pagination, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

How can I do something similar to `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResult` using JDBC template?

This is what I normally do using hql, but I need to use JDBC in this case (explanation below)

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT new MyWrapper(f.name, b.name) FROM Foo f JOIN f.bar b");
q.setFirstResult(startIndex).setMaxResults(maxNumRecords);
```

The reason I need to use JDBC is because I want to do this query:

```
SELECT b.name, f.name FROM Bar b JOIN Foo f ON f.id = b.foo_id;
```

In my `Foo` class has a `Bar` member, but my `Bar` class has no idea about the `Foo`. So I can't do this in HQL, hence the jdbc template.

```
SELECT b.name, f.name FROM Bar b JOIN b.foo
```

So my question is, is there an efficient and convenient way to limit the result set with JDBC template (just like with HQL)?
Or is there another way to achieve the join I wanted without having to use JDBC template?

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: You can use limit if it is mysql

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Post your solution here.

Comment: For interested people, here there are some answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771439