# Understanding of result memory for impala jdbc driver

Tags: java, database, jdbc, resultset, impala

I have written below code that get result set using prepared statement. We are using impala DB with jdbc driver.

```
  private void writeToCSV(File resultFile, ResultSet resultSet) throws IOException, SQLException {

    LOG.info("Result set fetch size : {}", resultSet.getFetchSize());

    try (BufferedWriter csvWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(resultFile))) {

      // Write headers
      int columnCount = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
      for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        csvWriter.write(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
        if (i < columnCount) {
          csvWriter.write(",");
        }
      }
      csvWriter.write("\n");

      // Write data
      int batchSize = 500; // You can adjust this based on your needs
      int currentCount = 0;

      while (resultSet.next()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
          csvWriter.write(resultSet.getString(i));
          if (i < columnCount) {
            csvWriter.write(",");
          }
        }
        csvWriter.write("\n");

        currentCount++;

        // Write to the file in chunks
        if (currentCount % batchSize == 0) {
          csvWriter.flush();
        }
      }

      // Flush any remaining data
      csvWriter.flush();
    }
  }
```

1. I want to understand, I have million records in memory, will record set load all of them at a time from impala DB or in batch. Also if it loads next batch, will previous record remain in memory or they will be removed.
2. Do I need to set the fetchsize. If result.getFetchSize always returns zero.

I tried executing this with 1 million records and saw huge spike in memory. If result works in batching, we should not have seen hugh spike in memory.

Comment: 1. if you select million data that will stay in memory. the code you share does not show what you select. if you do not select with pagination it will be very heavy and slow. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14566008/175554

2. if you want to do pagination yes you need to set fetchsize